# In Blazor updates, a StartUp class is no longer created on the client, as would then be done to add the services.AddAuthorizationCore ()

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm doing a tutorial, but it was created with the Blazor preview and the Startup class is no longer created on the client. I don't know where to put the following code.

````
          namespace Blazor.Client
       
    
         {
                public class Startup
                {
                    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
                    {
                        services.AddAuthorizationCore();
                    }
        
                public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
                {
                    app.AddComponent<App>("app");
                }
            }
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Hi! Provide a link to the tutorial so that other people can actually replicate your steps.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CEeeHBXTk0&t=723s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code should be placed in the Program.Main method of the Client.

Actually, `app.AddComponent<App>("app");` is already there in the form of
`builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");`

So all you need to do is add `builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();`
for `services.AddAuthorizationCore();`